# Xubuntu. Suddenly black

Tags: xubuntu, screen, lightdm, xfce

[image]

This is what my desktop looks like now. It's completely useless, will not do anything. Nothing to right click won't even minimize a program when it's clicked on. I've had this problem before and normally it's grey, but it usually goes away after i restart it again. This time it's completely stuck. I've tried everything I know down to dist upgrade and restarting lightdm. It happened after it boothung and would not start after installing Xubuntu desktop 4.12. I had to force shut down and it started but it was grey, now I'm not sure why it's black that happened after I tried logging in and out, logging in an Xfce session, logging in as guest, restarting, black. Everything works completely normal, I can even open the desktop folder in Thunar. Also it will not upgrade to Xubuntu 15.04 now, I didn't want to, but I tried it to see if it would solve the problem and nothing happens, it just closes the window and sits there like I never told it to do anything. I really really do not want to reinstall linux. As far as I can tell there's no bugs popping up.

Comment: If you end up needing to reinstall, one option may be to backup your /home directory. Then before booting the fresh install, you would replace the new install's home folder with yours. This way you would not have to re-do settings. However, there is a chance this method could re-introduce the current issue. To install your programs, you can just string those out into one command.

Comment: Are you able to get into the plain-text console with CTRL-ALT-F1?

Comment: If so you should be able to upgrade from there.

Comment: yes i am but how?

Comment: This should help: http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line